# how to use a for loop value outside of it?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I'm using a forEach loop inside of a function, But I want to use that value called **seenele** and **sadele** to the user basically the one who invokes the function, I want him to type the rule.
is that even possible?

Here's the code...

**

```
let seen;
let sad;
let result;


 onlyIf = (test, then) => {if(test)  then()};

 function dalla(seen, sad, rule){

   seen.forEach(seenFunc);
   function seenFunc(seenele){

     sad.forEach(mainFunc);
     function mainFunc(sadele){

         onlyIf(seenele + sadele == 7, () => console.log(seenele, sadele))
     }
     
   }
 }


 dalla([1,2,4], [2,3,5,6])
```

**

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly; anyway here's a refactoring: https://jsfiddle.net/khswrm3e/

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you tell us, what the purpose of the code is? What is the input data and what is the desired result?

Comment: @Chris, Thank you, the code looks like code now, it's a lot cleaner

Comment: @helle , hey, thank you! This part of the code **onlyIf(seenele + sadele == 7** I want the user or me when I call the function to be able to put the rule there, instead of it being hardcoded in the program

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just pass the predicate as a parameter:

```js
function joinBy(a, b, rule) {
    let result = [];

    a.forEach(
        itemA => b.forEach(
            itemB => {
                if (rule(itemA, itemB))
                    result.push([itemA, itemB])
            }
        )
    );

    return result;
}


console.log(
    joinBy(
        [1, 2, 4], 
        [2, 3, 5, 6], 
        (x, y) => x + y === 7
    )
)
```

More advanced example for further study:

```
let pairs = (a, b) => a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => [x, y]));

let splat = f => x => f(...x);

let joinBy = (a, b, rule) => pairs(a, b).filter(splat(rule));
```

Comment: Thanks, @georg !! I'll try to understand the code and write it myself as practice

Comment: that was too easy to understand, and that's not normal for me lol, thank you again

Comment: @HamzaAmin: glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!